# Which complex numbers satisfy $(-1)^z=1$ and $(-1)^z=-1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried to generalize the notion of parity towards complex numbers but Wolfram Alpha refuses to help me.

UPDATE

I meant separate equations, not a system of equations.

Comment: You realize that what you are asking is contradiction

Comment: then wrote them in polar form, the answer will be obvious.

Comment: $(-1)^{z}$ does not have a unique value so the question is meaningless.

Comment: do you know how to write 1 and -1 in polar form? e.g. $-1=e^{2ki\pi}$

Comment: @Arjang from that expressions it seems there are only real solutions or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find solutions to the two (separate) equations:

$(-1)^z = 1$

and $(-1)^z = -1$.

Let's tackle the first. Taking something to a complex power is complicated as the result can have multiple, even infinite, distinct values. So we need to be precise about what we want. So I'm going to interpret the problem as: "find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that *at least one possible* value of $(-1)^z$ will be equal to $1$".

When you're solving a purely real value problem like $a^x = b$, you take logs of both sides. You can do the same here with the complex valued logarithm. However, unlike the real logarithm, it can take an infinite number of values and you must consider the general form.

So: $\log (-1)^z = \log 1$

$z\log(-1) = \log 1$

Noting that $-1 = e^{i\pi(2n+1)}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1 = e^{i\pi 2m}, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ allow us to compute the general form of the complex logs and write:

$zi\pi(2n+1) = i\pi 2m$

$z = \frac{2m}{2n+1}, \ \ m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

and that's the general solution for the first equation. Note that, setting different integer values (including $0$) for $m,n$, we can generate all the solutions, including $z = 0, 2, -2, \frac 25, -\frac 23$ et cetera.

You can handle the second equation the same way, with the general solution here being $z = \frac{2m+1}{2n+1}, \ \ m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Specific solutions include $z=1, -1, \frac 35, -\frac 37$ and so on and so forth.

Note that the solutions to each equation are all rational real numbers.

Comment: I wonder if there is an equation to which satisfy all even Gaussian integers? Your solutions definitely give even and odd rationals

Comment: Not sure if it answers your question in the comment, but note that something as trivial as $1^z = 1$ would be satisfied by all complex $z$ (including Gaussian integers). If you use my method, you will have to be careful to avoid dividing by zero. You'll reach the point $z (i\pi 2n) = i\pi 2m$, and here you will get $z = \frac mn$ for $n \neq 0$. But you *must* consider separately the case where $n=0$, and in this case, *any* $z$ will satisfy the equation $z (i\pi 2n) = i\pi 2m$ with $m=n=0$. So that's why in this equation, all complex numbers are solutions, not just all rationals.

Comment: @Anixx If you want an equation of that form that is satisfied only by some subset of the Gaussian integers, I am not sure. You can try playing around with it and see if you can arrive at something, and you're welcome to verify it here (or in a new question).

Answer (score -2):

There is no $z$ such that  $(-1)^z=1$ and $(-1)^z=-1$.

Proof : assume there is a number $z$ such that  $(-1)^z=1$ and $(-1)^z=-1$.
then $(-1)^z=1=(-1)^z=-1$

or $1=-1$. contradiction QED.

Comment: I did not mean at the same time! These are separate equations!

Comment: Yes but, just to be clear, this was the correct answer BEFORE you UPDATED the question :)